# WPF Combobox in view not updating when bound property in viewmodel updated

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a Combobox in a view, bound to a viewmodel with an ObservableCollection of a custom class of mine. This custom class is simply a wrapper for an Enum which holds the value, and a string which is the enum description attribute. The combobox sets the DisplayMemberPath property to this name property, to display a more human readable description attribute value, rather than the enum itself

I am finding that when I set the ItemsSource of the combobox to a collection of these Enum wrapper classes, and then set the SelectedItem property to one of these items, the combobox is not updating in the UI when I start my application. If I change this to a List of strings, it seems to work.

Here is my combobox:

```xml
    <ComboBox
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
        IsEditable="False"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableTags}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTag, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

My custom class the combobox is bound to a collection of:

```
public class EnumNamePair : ObservableObject
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => SetProperty(ref name, value);
    }

    private Enum enumValue;
    public Enum EnumValue
    {
        get => enumValue;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref enumValue, value);
            Name = enumValue.GetEnumDescription();
        }
    }

    public EnumNamePair(Enum enumValue)
    {
        EnumValue = enumValue;
    }
}
```

Part of my viewmodel:

```
private ObservableCollection<EnumNamePair> selectableTags = new();
public ObservableCollection<EnumNamePair> SelectableTags
{
    get => selectableTags;
    set => SetProperty(ref selectableTags, value);
}

private EnumNamePair selectedTag;
public EnumNamePair SelectedTag
{
    get => selectedTag;
    set => SetProperty(ref selectedTag, value);
}

public TaggingRuleViewModel(string tag)
{
    SelectableTags = new List<EnumNamePair>(
        Enum.GetValues(typeof(AllowedTag)).Cast<AllowedTag>().Select(x => new EnumNamePair(x)));

    SelectedTag = SelectableTags.First(x => x.EnumValue.ToString() == tag),
}
```

This is simplified but recreates the problem. I have tried various additional raisings of OnPropertyChanged for my bound properties, altering the Readonly/Editable property setters on the combobox, dumbing down my viewmodels/custom class (it used to have a single getter for the name property rather than set on setting the EnumValue etc). All that seems to work is changing the list of my custom class to a list of strings, and handling the conversion in the viewmodel. I know there are other ways of handling showing an enum description attribute in a combobox but at this point I simply want to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: Are you implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on you view model class?

Comment: You'll show more complete code. As @C1sc0 already wrote, most likely you do not have an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged in your Model. It would be better if you upload your solution (in the minimum working version) to GitHub and provide a link to it.
Also, for your task, an implementation using IValueConverter is much better suited. How to represent a value is the "case" of the View, not the ViewModel.

Comment: Yes I'm using Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm and my viewmodel class(es) implement ObservableObject, which is where the 'SetProperty' methods come from in my property setters. I'll give a converter a go and upload a mwe solution to github if I'm still having issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converter implementation example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Core2022.SO.JosephWard
{
    public static class EnumExtensions
    {
        private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, string>> enums
            = new Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        public static string GetEnumDescription<T>(this T value)
            where T : Enum
        {
            Type enumType = value.GetType();
            if (!enums.TryGetValue(enumType, out Dictionary<string, string>? descriptions))
            {
                descriptions = enumType.GetFields()
                    .ToDictionary(
                        info => info.Name,
                        info => ((DescriptionAttribute?)info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)?.FirstOrDefault())?.Description ?? info.Name);
                enums.Add(enumType, descriptions);
            }

            string name = value.ToString();
            if (descriptions.TryGetValue(name, out string? description))
            {
                return description;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("UnexpectedValue", nameof(value));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Core2022.SO.JosephWard
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(Enum), typeof(string))]
    public class EnumToDescriptionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is Enum @enum)
                return @enum.GetEnumDescription();
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public static EnumToDescriptionConverter Instance { get; } = new EnumToDescriptionConverter();
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Core2022.SO.JosephWard
{
    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(EnumToDescriptionConverter))]
    public class EnumToDescriptionExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return EnumToDescriptionConverter.Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Core2022.SO.JosephWard
{
    public enum AllowedTag
    {
        [Description("Value not set")]
        None,
        [Description("First value")]
        First,
        [Description("Second value")]
        Second
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Core2022.SO.JosephWard
{
    public class EnumsViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<AllowedTag> Tags { get; } = new ObservableCollection<AllowedTag>()
        { AllowedTag.None, AllowedTag.Second, AllowedTag.First };
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2022.SO.JosephWard.EnumsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2022.SO.JosephWard"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="EnumsWindow" Height="150" Width="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:EnumsViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AllowedTag}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={local:EnumToDescription}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Eld, thanks for your answer, I'll have a go implementing this and mark as answer if it does the job. Thanks! I had avoided converters because of the split nature of the combobox items source and selected item properties, since both would need converters presumably to maintain the enum usage in my viewmodel?

Comment: Hi, @JosephWard.
A solution similar to EnumNamePair does not make sense to apply only if the Descriptor can change at runtime. To work with Attributes, such a solution turns out to be excessively complex and confusing.

Comment: @JosephWard, Your implementation of EnumNamePair does not define comparison by value. Therefore, different instances, but with the same values, will still be considered different. Because of this, there will be difficulties when setting the EnumNamePair obtained from the Enum, and not from a previously created and immutable list. And creating such a list and then working exclusively through it, and not with the original Enum, is another additional complication of the logic.

Comment: Ah ok, I did think that might be a cause so I did have a version that would set the selected item from the itemssource, however this also failed.

Comment: A converter did the trick. I was concerned about the interaction between the items source and selected item using a converter, and that both properties might need a converter, however just using a converter for a single enum in the itemstemplate worked, and doesn't mess around with the selected item